# Start chapters from a new page

Tags: chapters, reledpar

As I understand, chapters should produce headings on the new page. However, it does not work in the example below probably because of conflict between some packages.

I would also like to have every `\subsection` starting from a new page.

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
%% Additional note from LLT: you don't need fontspec or xelatex for reledmac or reledpar to work. However, if your document _does_ involve different languages with different scripts/fonts (e.g. English and Greek or Arabic etc), then it's a good idea to use those packages -- see https://www.overleaf.com/read/wfdxqhcyyjxz for an example
%
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian, french]{babel}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.5in, top=1in]{geometry} %, showframe]
\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}

\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.3\textwidth}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\setgoalfraction{0.8}
\numberlinefalse
\begin{document}   
\begin{sloppypar}

\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
    \selectlanguage{russian}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart[
            \chapter*{\foreignlanguage{russian}{ИСТОРИЯ ПЕРВАЯ}}
            \section*{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Суета Вокруг Дивана}}]
            \pend
            \newpage
            \pstart[
            \newpage\subsection*{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Глава первая}}]
            \epigraph{\itshape 
            Учитель: Дети, запишите предложение: «Рыба сидела на дереве». 
            \newline 
            Ученик: А разве рыбы сидят на деревьях? 
            \newline 
            Учитель: Ну... Это была сумасшедшая рыба. }{Школьный анекдот}
            \pend
            \pstart
            Я приближался к месту моего назначения. Вокруг меня, прижимаясь к самой дороге, зеленел лес, изредка уступая место полянам, поросшим желтой осокою. Солнце садилось уже который час, все никак не могло сесть и висело низко над горизонтом. Машина катилась по узкой дороге, засыпанной хрустящим гравием. Крупные камни я пускал под колесо, и каждый раз в багажнике лязгали и громыхали пустые канистры.
            \pend
            \pstart
            Справа из леса вышли двое, ступили на обочину и остановились, глядя в мою сторону. Один из них поднял руку. Я сбросил газ, их рассматривая. Это были, как мне показалось, охотники, молодые люди, может быть, немного старше меня. Их лица понравились мне, и я остановился. Тот, что поднимал руку, просунул в машину смуглое горбоносое лицо и спросил, улыбаясь:
            \pend
            \pstart
            – Вы нас не подбросите до Соловца?
            \pend
            \newpage
            \pstart[
            \newpage
            \chapter*{\foreignlanguage{russian}{ИСТОРИЯ ВТОРАЯ}}
            \section*{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Суета Сует}}]
            \pend
            \newpage
            \pstart[
            \newpage
            \subsection*{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Глава вторая}}]
            \epigraph{\itshape 
            ...Опустевший дом превратился в логово лисиц и барсуков, и потому здесь могут появляться странные оборотни и призраки.}{А.  У э д а}
            \pend
            \pstart
            Я проснулся посреди ночи оттого, что в комнате разговаривали. Разговаривали двое, едва слышным шепотом. Голоса были очень похожи, но один был немного сдавленный и хрипловатый, а другой выдавал крайнее раздражение.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
    \selectlanguage{english}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart[
            \chapter*{THE FIRST TALE}
            \section*{Run Around a Sofa}]
            \pend
            \newpage
            \pstart[
            \newpage
            \subsection*{Chapter 1}]
            \epigraph{\itshape 
            Teacher: Children, write down the proposition: “The fish was sitting in a tree.”
            \newline 
            Pupil: But is it true that fish sit in trees?
            \newline 
            Teacher: Well… it was a crazy fish.}{School Joke}
            \pend
            \pstart
            I was approaching my destination. All around, pressing up against the very edge of the road, the green of the forest yielded now and then to a meadow overgrown with yellow sedge. The sun had been setting for an hour and still couldn’t make it, hanging low on the horizon. The car rolled along, crunching on a gravel surface. I steered around the bigger rocks, and each maneuver caused the empty canisters to rattle and clang in the trunk.
            \pend
            \pstart
            A couple of men came out of the woods on the right and stopped on the shoulder, looking in my direction. One of them raised his hand. I took my foot off the gas, scrutinizing the pair. They seemed to be hunters, young, and maybe a bit older than myself. Deciding I liked their looks, I stopped. The one who had raised his hand stuck his swarthy, hawk-nosed face through the window and asked, grinning,
            \pend
            \pstart 
            “Could you give us a lift to Solovetz?”
            \pend
            \newpage
            \pstart[
            \newpage
            \chapter*{THE SECOND TALE}
            \section*{Vanity of Vanities}]
            \pend
            \newpage
            \pstart[
            \newpage
            \subsection*{Chapter 2}]
            \epigraph{\itshape 
            … The deserted house became the lair of foxes and badgers, and that is why weird spirits and shape-shifters can now appear here.}{A. Weda}
            \pend
            \pstart
            I woke up in the middle of the night because a conversation was going on in the room. Two voices were talking in a barely audible whisper. They were very similar, but one was a bit stifled and hoarse and the other betrayed an extreme irritation.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs} 
\Columns
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

Ideally, I'd like to have pages:

1. THE FIRST TALE, Run Around a Sofa
2. Chapter 1
3. (Chapter 2...)
4. THE SECOND TALE, Vanity of Vanities
5. Chapter 1
6. (Chapter 2...)

and right now I have this

[image]

Comment: how about the \newpage command doesnt this work? im on phone atm so i can not test myself

Comment: @der bender no it doesn't,  it was the first thing I tried

Comment: mmh well then where did you put it. i can imagine that inside one of the columns it doesnt work but outside the pairs environment i think it could... you would need to start a new environment then though. minor unrelated comment: a russian english book wont need a french language pack? or would it?

Comment: can you post your build chain and all warnings or errors if any. only thing i can imagine else is that it does not work with chapters inside the pstart pend combination?

Comment: @derbender I edited my code in the question: basically, I tried to do it within and outside \pstart\pend - no results. About build chain I am not quite sure what you want; I use overleaf projects  - is it the logs from a compilation? It is a very big file.
About French - yes, from time to time there are some French words used with accents and stuff - that's why I need it.

Comment: Well the only (stupid) thing I could come up with so far is to start every new page in a different `pairs` environment.